# A compact subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$ is not necessarily closed.

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compact sets are closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239998/compact-sets-are-closed)

We know that if $X$ is Hausdorff, then a compact subset $Y$ of $X$ must be closed. Without the assumption, this claim is not true. But can you come up with a counterexample?

Comment: Do you know any non-Hausdorff spaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give any set with at least two elements the indiscrete topology. Then any nonempty proper subset is compact but not closed.