# Closed vs. compact surface

Tags: general-topology, compactness, manifolds-with-boundary

Wikipedia defines a [surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)) to be a two-dimensional manifold, and a [closed surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Closed_surfaces) to be a surface that is compact and without boundary.  Am I correct that this definition of "closed surface" is *not* equivalent to the definition "a surface that is closed (as a [Hausdorff space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space))"?  A "closed surface" is defined to be compact, but a compact Hausdorff space [is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/240008/268333).

So, for example, a disk that includes its boundary is not a closed surface, but it is a surface that is closed (topologically).  I find this definition very confusing.

**Edit:** As Joppy points out in their answer, this same issue applies to any closed manifold, not just two-dimensional surfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're partly correct. A "closed manifold" is a manifold which is compact and has no boundary, and a "closed surface" is just a specialisation of that definition to dimension 2, and this is not equivalent to the definition of being closed as a Hausdorff space.

But any space is closed in itself, so every surface is topologically closed, so this is an uninteresting fact. This is why the re-use of the word "closed" is not too confusing.

Comment: Every space is closed in itself, but not every subspace of Euclidean space is closed with respect to the inherited Euclidean topology.  So I think the "closed-ness" of the manifold is trivial if you're thinking intrinsically, but nontrivial if you're thinking of it extrinsically, as being embedded in Euclidean space.

Comment: But thanks for pointing out that this same issue applies to any closed manifold.  The [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold) points out that "The notion of closed manifold is unrelated with that of a closed set. A disk with its boundary is a closed subset of the plane, but not a closed manifold."

Comment: @tparker But note that a closed manifold embedded in Euclidean space is compact and hence closed (and bounded) as a subspace.

Comment: @AlexProvost True, closed as a manifold implies closed topologically, but not vice versa.