# Is the proof of "compact sets are closed" right?

Tags: analysis, compactness

Proposition 3 If $K$ is a compact set in$\mathbb{R}^m$, then

a) $K$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$,

Zorich's proof.
We shall show that any point $a\in\mathbb{R}^m$ that is a limit point of $K$ must belong to $K$.
Suppose $a \notin K$.
For each point $x\in K$ we construct **a neighborhood $G(x)$ such that $a$ has a neighborhood disjoint from $G(x)$**.
The set $\{G(x)\},x\in K$, consisting of all such neighborhoods forms an open covering of the compact set $K$,
from which we can select a finite covering $G(x_1),\ldots,G(x_n)$.
If now $O_i(a)$ is a neighborhood of $a$ such that $G(x_i)\cap O_i(a)=\varnothing$,
then the set $O(a)=\bigcap_{i=1}^nO_i(a)$ is also a neighborhood of $a$ , and obviously $K\cap O(a)=\varnothing$.
Thus $a$ cannot be a limit point of $K$.

I will paraphrase the Zorich's proof and point out my doubt.
From $a \notin K$, Zorich **wants to prove** $a$ is not a limit point of $K$.
His method is to construct $x \in G(x)$ which satisfies $G(x) \cap O(a) = \emptyset$ where $O(a)$ is a neighbourhood of $a$.
But I think the necessary condition of this kind of $G(x)$ can be constructed relies on that **$a$ is not a limit point** which is what he wants to prove.
Because if $a$ is a limit point, then every $O(a)$ contains at least one point $x^{\prime} \in K$, and so this $x^{\prime}$ can not construct a $G(x^{\prime})$.
So as I see, Zorich **presupposes his conclusion** and fails to prove it (he is in a vicious circle).

[image]
(It is from Mathematical Analysis I, Zorich, p.414)

I think his proof should only construct a neighborhood $G(x)$ such that $a \notin G(x)$.
And then there are finitely many $G(x_i)$ subcovers $K$ and at the same time $a \notin G(x)$.
Then we can find a $r = \min\{d(G_1(x), a), \cdots, d(G_m(x), a)\}$ and construct a ball $B(a, r) \cap K = \emptyset$.
In this way the proof can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of $G(x)$ only needs $x\neq a$, because $\mathbb R^m$ is a Hausdorff space, meaning that for every two points $x_1,x_2$, we can find open neighborhoods $x_i\in O_i$, for $i=1,2$, so that $O_1\cap O_2=\emptyset$. In particular, since $a\notin K$ (by assumption), every point $x\in K$ is different from $a$, therefore $x$ has a neighborhood $G(x)$ such that $a$ has a neighborhood disjoint from $G(x)$.

The fact that $a$ is not a limit point of $K$ means that $a$ has a open neighborhood disjoint from $K$ itself. A priori, if $O(x)$ is a neighborhood of $a$ disjoint from $G(x)$, it may well be that $O(x)\cap K\neq\emptyset$. In particular, it's not enough to say $a\notin G(x)$, because if $G(x)$ is not closed and $a$ is in the boundary, then the distance between $a$ and $G(x)$ is $0$. If you want to correct that, you would have to require that $a$ is not in the closure of $G(x)$, but that is equivalent to the $G(x)$ in the proof by Zorich (the complement of $G(x)$ would be the neighborhood of $a$ disjoint from $G(x)$).

Comment: I can accept what you say that $x \neq a$ implies there are two disjoint neighborhood $G(x)$ and $O(a)$. But I am still confused with that for the limit point $b$, every neighborhood of $b$ has at least one $x_i$ in it. I will think harder. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I get something in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/400211. I think if I set the radius of $G(x)$ as $\frac{1}{2}d(a, x)$, my answer will be correct. And I will think harder about Zorich's proof and your explanation.